# Link a guard (canDeactivate) and a component without use RouterModule

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-router-guards

I call a component on a HTML page like this:

```
<app-my-component></<app-my-component>
```

What I want it's link a guard `canDeactivate` with the component `my-component`. This component is never called by a route, so I don't add a path in `RouterModule`. I use it in 2 different pages.

How to link the component and the guard without adding something like that:

```
{ path: 'my-component', component: MyComponent, canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard] }
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a good solution. But, you can actually use `*ngIf` based on your requirements to show or hide.

```
<app-my-component *ngif="some logic here"></<app-my-component>
```

without routing path, you won't get the guard feature.

Comment: I want to use CanDeactivate for keeping the user from losing data by leaving the page. The problem if I use `*ngIf` is I will not know if the user go to the previous page or change page with the navbar (for example). But it works when I use a guard with canDeactivate

Comment: I know that, but without declaring the component in router, you won't be able to get that guard feature.

Comment: So I cannot use `<app-my-component></<app-my-component>` if I want to get the guard feature ? I must call the component with a route ?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know.

Comment: Rather than having `*ngif` which will require a boolean flag in all the component's class file, I would suggest you to create a structural directive as `*hasPermission`.
Follow the resource https://juristr.com/blog/2018/02/angular-permission-directive/

Comment: I want to use the guard after the render of the page for keeping the user from losing data by leaving the page before submit. So I don't need a condition for knowing if the page can be rendered or not.

Answer (score 0):

The Guard is just like a service. You can inject it into a component and call the desired
method . But it will not behave as a Guard (stop routing etc) and you will have to manage the logic yourself.